# Set delay within event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code -

```
hits.on('rowSelected', function (evt) {
    setTimeout(function() { alert('hi'); }, 5000); 
});
```

so I have a `hits` table. When a row is selected within that table, this event gets fired. The issue is I want to not be able to select a row again for 5 seconds. IMO, this isn't working because the event on the table gets fired every time a row is selected without giving the `setTimeout` time to delay.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Use an outer variable as a flag that is checked when the event happens. If the flag is set, return. If not, set the flag, do your work, and unset the flag in the setTimeout.

Comment: Or give your handler function a name, unbind it when the event happens, and re-bind it in the setTimeout. No variables to maintain that way.

Comment: Not clear from the question if you're asking how to prevent the user from selecting a row at all for 5 seconds, or you just want to stop the code in your `'rowSelected'` handler from running more than once within five seconds. What does it mean for a row to be "selected" (as compared to "clicked")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most elegant solution I could come up with is below, using a button to simulate the behavior.

It works as follows:

1. Bind a named event handler (`handler`) to the element, and use jQuery's [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to only execute it once.
2. In the event handler, handle the event.
3. Use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to wait 5 seconds before re-binding the event handler for the next execution.

```js
let button = $('#button');

button.one('click', function handler() {
  console.log('clicked'); // handle event here

  setTimeout(() => $(this).one('click', handler), 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click me!</button>
```

This approach has the following benefits:

- Does not require external variables to hold the state of the event handler (i.e. whether it's active or not).
- Does not require unbinding of the event handler, as every time it's only bound for only a single execution.
- Does not pollute the outer scope with a named event handler.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend is making use of a variable to store whether the element has been clicked or not.

Run your `setTimeout()` inside an `if` conditional that checks against this variable. Once the element is clicked, update the variable so that it cannot be clicked again. Then, once the timeout has resolved, enable the click again.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var hits = $("p");
var clickable = true; // It's clickable by default

hits.on('click', function(evt) {
  if (clickable) { // Check whether it can be clicked
    clickable = false; // Once clicked, don't allow further clicks
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('hi');
      clickable = true; // Make it clickable again
    }, 5000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click this paragraph.</p>
```

Hope this helps! :)